# Grouping values by date into arrays - cannot bridge from Obj-C

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to take an array or JSON data and group the values in the array by date using the following code:

```
func groupTrips (trips: JSON) -> [[Trip?]] {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var groupedTrips:[[Trip?]] = []
    var group: [Trip] = []
    for (index, tripRaw):(String, JSON) in trips {
      let trip = Trip(trip: tripRaw)
      if index == "0" && calendar.compareDate(trip.pickup, toDate: NSDate.init(), toUnitGranularity: .Day) != .OrderedSame {
        groupedTrips.append([nil])
      }
      if let lastTrip = group.last {
        let order = calendar.compareDate(trip.pickup, toDate: lastTrip.pickup, toUnitGranularity: .Day)
        if order == .OrderedSame {
          group.append(trip)
        } else {
          groupedTrips.append(group)
          group = [trip]
        }
      } else {
        group.append(trip)
      }
    }
    groupedTrips.append(group)
    return groupedTrips
  }
```

When I try to run the code, I get an error on the 3rd to last line `groupedTrips.append(group)`: `Thead 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` And in my console, I get `fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C`. My Trip class is just a simple Swift class that parsed the JSON element into objects.

Comment: I don't really know if it's the best way to fix the issue but generally I change the class to a struct. Works unless you extend/implement something and if you don't mind that it's value type rather than a reference type.
I believe that you can also generally fix it extending NSObject, but not so sure on that one.

Comment: @TedHuinink: It looks like changing to a struct worked. Probably a good idea if I want to use the simplest object type possible to contain values. Turn your comment into an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know if it's the best way to fix the issue but generally I change the class to a struct. Works unless you extend/implement something and if you don't mind that it's value type rather than a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Comparable](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Comparable_Protocol/). Implementing this in your Trip reference would allow you to use the sort() function. Apart from that, I would recommend digesting [Swift's functional aspects](https://www.weheartswift.com/higher-order-functions-map-filter-reduce-and-more/). I think your code could be cleaned up and simplified significantly.